# How to solve this recurrence relations?

Tags: recurrence

I am trying  solve this recurrence relations. I read a similar question in this site but it wasn't my answer.

```
T(n)=T(sqrt(n))    if n>4

T(n)=1             if n=4
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `n` assumed to be an integer? What if it's not a perfect square? Does that mean `T(n)` has no value? Can you link to the most related, similar question you've found and explain why it doesn't answer your question? If integers are assumed, then it's clear that `T(n)` has a value only if `n` is of the form `4**(2**k)` for any natural number (1,2,3,...) `k`. And that value would always be `1`.

Comment: I first got below answer but i thought This can not be true and should rich a formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your definition:

```
T(x) = 1 for all numbers of type 4^(2^n) for n being a natural number
T(x) not defined for all others
```

Comment: Yes, I believe that's what I said in my comment to the OP, if it's only defined over natural numbers.

Comment: question text hasn't another explanation.I think your answer is correct.